# ¿Por qué no se arroja el resultado con estos números?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sintaxis, memoria

Soy principiante en la programación y comencé a resolver el problema 1A "Theatre Square" de Codeforces. El problema es que cuando “n” o “m” son un número muy grande (100000000 o más) el programa directamente no devuelve el resultado que se busca. Esto no ocurre con la variable “a”, supongo que es por uno de los condicionales que coloqué. Mi duda es si este problema es un tema de memoria o algún error en el código. ¡Muchas gracias!

````
j = input()
numeros = j.split(' '
)
n = int(numeros[0])
m = int(numeros[1])
a = int(numeros [2])
contador=0 

while n>0 and m>0:
    if a==m or a == n:
        while n>0:
            n -= a
            contador += 0.5
        while m>0:
            m -= a 
            contador += 0.5
    elif a>n or a>m:
        contador +=1
        break
    else:
        while n>0:
            n -= a
            contador += 1
        while m>0:
            m -= a
            contador += 1
    
print(round(contador)) ```
````

Comment: Con 100000000, los bucles pueden ser eternos. No creo que sea un problema de memoria o de otro tipo. Piensa en un modo de hacer el cálculo sin recurrir a bucles. De todos modos, antes de ponerte a resolver el problema con número grandes deberías probar con más tests sencillos, y ayúdate de un dibujo para entender mejor el resultado que tiene que dar. Por ejemplo, n=1 m=5 a=4 necesita 2 losetas para cubrir todo.

Comment: No sabía eso. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

En resumen: tienes un área rectangular de n x m y la debes cubrir con baldosas de a x a.

```
def flagstone(n ,m, a):
    lado1 = math.ceil (n / a)
    lado2 = math.ceil (m / a)
    return lado1 * lado2
```

Hay que cubrir cada lado con *largo / a* baldosas. Como el cálculo puede dar fracciones, usamos `ceil()` para lograr el siguiente entero.

Entonces tenemos un rectangulo con sus lados medidos en *baldosas*. ¿Cuantas necesito? Basta multiplicar un lado por el otro.

**Demo**

```
import math

def flagstone(n ,m, a):
    lado1 = math.ceil (n / a)
    lado2 = math.ceil (m / a)
    return lado1 * lado2

tests = [
    (6, 6, 4),
    (4, 4, 4),
    (1, 1, 4),
    (16, 16, 4),
    (1, 1000, 4),
    (1000, 1000, 1),
    (1_000_000_000, 1_000_000_000, 500)
]

for test in tests:
    n, m, a = test
    print(f"{n:_d} {m:_d} {a:_d} -> {flagstone(n, m, a):_d}")
```

produce

```
6 6 4 -> 4
4 4 4 -> 1
1 1 4 -> 1
16 16 4 -> 16
1 1_000 4 -> 250
1_000 1_000 1 -> 1_000_000
1_000_000_000 1_000_000_000 500 -> 4_000_000_000_000

Process finished with exit code 0
```